# 12 volt car charging system - I have to use a lower voltage for the deep cycle battery

Tags: power-supply, power

Two new 100Ah deep AGM type batteries to be charged with 2.25 volt/cell in our motorhome (I just edited the instructions.) The charger in the car battery management system charges with 13.6 volts. I have to lose 1 volt. The batteries are also charged when I am driving with the alternator - the correct voltage for the starter battery - but too high for the AGM battery. The AGM supplies the house consumers - the nominal 12 volt is needed. I have to regulate the charging cable going into the AGM battery - coming from the alternator and the build in charger.

We plan a long trip and I do not want to cook the new AGM batteries.

Comment: 2.25 V/cell = 13.5 V/battery

Comment: What is your question? Please do visit the help centre. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

you good to go mate, agm's can handle a bulk charge up to 14-15v,13.6v will be fine as a fully charged agm is usually 13.8v resting.as for your battery management system it will sort it out. I think it means it will hold at 13.5v as most all '12v' batteries charge at 14v +. just make sure they both at same voltage resting if connecting in series or parallel. And its not 1v its 0.1v ...nothing

Comment: This isn't an answer to a question. Please do visit the help centre. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: About the only way to get into trouble is with linked vehicle and house batteries is if you add another method of charging such as solar panels on the roof, or flatten the vehicle battery by not isolating the vehicle battery from the house load.

Comment: @vu2nanGenuine query. What is wrong wity this answer? Apart from its colloquial style :-)